# Python plot not starting from center

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to draw a plot inside tkinter using Animation function of matplotlib. Now I save the x and y in a file and read from the file to plot the graph. Since I want my graph to remain in center I set the xlim in that..but it's not working..rather my graph is starting from o point and not from the center.

```py
def animate(i):

    global j
    xs = []
    ys = []

    pid = os.getpid()
    p = psutil.Process(pid=pid)
    p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
    usage = p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
    with open("harry.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(usage))
        f.write(",")
        f.write(str(j))
        f.write("\n")

    graph_data = open('harry.txt', 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            y, x = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)

    ax.plot(xs,ys,color='b')
    ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, j - 50), right=j + 50)
    j = j + 1
    return line,

root = Tk.Tk()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.clear()
line, = ax.plot(xs,ys,color='b')
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=False)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Output that I'm getting
[image]

Expected Output
[image]

where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Looks like that `j` starts from 0 (as you haven't given a value here). So initially you will get the x-axis at origin

Comment: I have defined j outside the animate function with 0

Comment: I have also added the expected output for reference

Comment: Try removing the line `ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, j - 50), right=j + 50)`.

Comment: If I do that plot will squeeze. So, I have time in x axis..which will keep on increasing and after a period of time if there is no "xlim", the x axis will start overlapping.

Comment: Then you need to set `right=j` instead of `right=j+50`.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code (also, why is there a comma in the return statement?)